# Youtube viewer program

Tags: youtube, http-error

While using MShawon's YouTube Viewer Program, I faced some issues. Everything was normal until this message comes:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\YouTube-Viewer-master\youtube_viewer.py", line 43, in <module>
    from youtubeviewer.download_driver import *
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\YouTube-Viewer-master\youtubeviewer\download_driver.py", line 29, in <module>
    import undetected_chromedriver._compat as uc
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'undetected_chromedriver._compat'
```

I tried `pip install undetected-chromedriver` again but a bunch of "Requirements already statified" appears in front of me. Then I tried `pip install undetected-chromedriver==3.2.1`, it works. But when I tried to run the program:

```
Yb  dP  dP"Yb  88   88 888888 88   88 88""Yb 888888
 YbdP  dP   Yb 88   88   88   88   88 88__dP 88__
  8P   Yb   dP Y8   8P   88   Y8   8P 88""Yb 88""
 dP     YbodP  `YbodP'   88   `YbodP' 88oodP 888888

                        Yb    dP 88 888888 Yb        dP 888888 88""Yb
                         Yb  dP  88 88__    Yb  db  dP  88__   88__dP
                          YbdP   88 88""     YbdPYbdP   88""   88"Yb
                           YP    88 888888    YP  YP    888888 88  Yb


           [ GitHub : https://github.com/MShawon/YouTube-Viewer ]


+-------------------------- Version: 1.8.0 --------------------------+

Getting Chrome Driver...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\YouTube-Viewer-master\youtube_viewer.py", line 1003, in <module>
    osname, exe_name = download_driver(patched_drivers=patched_drivers)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\YouTube-Viewer-master\youtubeviewer\download_driver.py", line 112, in download_driver
    uc.install()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver\_compat.py", line 262, in install
    ChromeDriverManager(executable_path, target_version, *args, **kwargs).install()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver\_compat.py", line 192, in install
    self.fetch_chromedriver()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver\_compat.py", line 221, in fetch_chromedriver
    ver = self.get_release_version_number().vstring
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver\_compat.py", line 211, in get_release_version_number
    return LooseVersion(urlopen(self.__class__.DL_BASE + path).read().decode())
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 216, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 525, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 634, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 563, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 496, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 643, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

Just what the heck is this!? Can somebody explain?

Comment: For thosee unfamiliar with this, could you [edit] you question and add more context about what this program does?, where is your code?